# Bluemix CLIで bx api しても接続が失敗する

Tags: bluemix

今日初めてBluemixを使い始めた者です。
CLIをインストール⇒PC再起動後、コマンドプロンプトより接続を試みましたが、下記のエラーとなります。

```
bx api https://api.ng.bluemix.net
```

> API エンドポイント: https://api.ng.bluemix.net
>   失敗
>   Get https://api.ng.bluemix.net/v2/info: dial tcp 23.37.155.59:443: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

ちなみに、試しにブラウザのURLに「https://api.ng.bluemix.net」を貼り付けてアクセスした場合は、問題無く接続できました。

ネットで事象を調べてみましたが、何もヒットせず・・・
CLIインストール後に何か環境設定など必要なのでしょうか？

環境: Windows 7

Comment: 念のため、Windowsやセキュリティソフトのファイヤーウォール等の設定は確認されましたか？

Comment: 失敗してるのは、https://api.ng.bluemix.net/v2/info では？多分、ブラウザアクセスでは失敗するのが正しいんだと思いますが...

Answer (score 0):

一応、Windowsファイアーウォールとアンチウィルスソフトは無効化してみましたが、
それでもダメでした。

が、昨日帰宅して自宅PCからコマンドを叩いてみたところ、正常に接続できました。

なので、多分会社のネットワーク上の問題かと思います。
お騒がせしました。
ご回答頂いた方、有難うございました。